# XSLT: How can I identify the list of values are same?

Tags: iteration, xslt-1.0

I got the following xml snippet.

```
<Root>
    <SomeTags></SomeTags>
    <Values>
        <dateFrom>date 1<dateFrom>
        <dateEnd>date 2<dateEnd>
        <value1>10</value1>
        <value2>5</value2>
    </Values>
   More Values here....
    .....................
    .....................
    <Values>
        <dateFrom>date n<dateFrom>
        <dateEnd>date  n+1<dateEnd>
        <value1>10</value1>
        <value2>5</value2>
    </Values>
</Root>
```

I want to compare all `<value1>` values and `<value2>` values. If they are same, I want to compress the whole as following:

If values1 == same in all Values and If values2== same in all Values then this should the output.

```
<Values>
    <dateFrom>date 1<dateFrom> should be from the first Values item
    <dateEnd>date  n+1<dateEnd> should be from the last Values item
    <value1>10</value1>
    <value2>5</value2>
</Values>
```

Else
    different template.

How can i achieve this in XSLT (1.0) in BizTalk 2009 ?
I know iteration. for-each. But is there a way to break as in procedural language. Can I somehow compare each value and return a boolean saying all values are same or not.. ??

Thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Values">
  <xsl:if test=
  "not(preceding-sibling::Values
              [value1=current()/value1 and value2=current()/value2])">
   <Values>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="value1|value2"/>
   </Values>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following well-formed XML document** (produced from the severely malformed text that is provided in the question):

```
<t>
    <Values>
        <dateFrom>date 1</dateFrom>
        <dateEnd>date 2</dateEnd>
        <value1>10</value1>
        <value2>5</value2>
    </Values>
    <somethingElse/>
    <Values>
        <dateFrom>date n</dateFrom>
        <dateEnd>date  n+1</dateEnd>
        <value1>10</value1>
        <value2>5</value2>
    </Values>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<t>
   <Values>
      <value1>10</value1>
      <value2>5</value2>
   </Values>
   <somethingElse/>
</t>
```

**Explanation**:

Just applying the most fundamental design pattern of XSLT: Using and overriding the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.

Comment: Hi Dmitre, Thanks for your help. But your solution doesn't work. I have multiple sets of Values. Not just 2. It can be any no of Values. 1) The whole set of values should be compressed into one Values if all values1 have same value and all values2 have same value. 2) Also the dateFrom should be taken from the first Values item and the dateTo should be taken from the last Values item. Regards

Comment: @user1872757, Please, *edit* your question and provide a more representative XML document and a more precise explanation what needs to be done. Please, also provide the exact wanted result for that XML document.